# MVC Random Word Generator

Tags: java, model-view-controller

So I am creating an MVC Random Word generator that submits user input and retrieves it. I am having a hard time with my RandomWordModel class. I created an ArrayList of strings that are supposed to store user input and then retrieve it one the user presses the "Retrieve Word" button.

public class RandomWordModel {

```
private ArrayList<String> randomWords;

public RandomWordModel()
{

}
public String putWord(String userWords) {
    randomWords.add(userWords);
    return userWords;
}

public String getWord() {
    Collections.shuffle(randomWords);
    String userInput = randomWords.get(randomWords.size());
    return userInput;
}
```

This is what I have so far and it is not really working for some reason. I'm not sure if I am doing this wrong but if anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to create a full MVC model for that.

I would personally go with something simpler like below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class test2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter string > ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        String words[] = new String[input.length()];
        if(!input.isBlank())
            words = input.split(" ");

        System.out.println(words[rand.nextInt(words.length)]); 
    }
}
```

[Edited Code Below]

As per your requirement you can split the above code into MVC rather easily. It is very much just rearranging the codes.

RandomWordView.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomWordView{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter string > ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        RandomWordModel rwm;

        if(!input.isBlank()){
            rwm = new RandomWordModel(input.split(" "));
            System.out.println(RandomWordController.getRandomWord(rwm));
        }
    }
}
```

RandomWordModel.java

```
public class RandomWordModel{
    String wordArr[];

    public RandomWordModel(String wordArr[]){
        this.wordArr = wordArr;
    }

    public String[] getWordArr(){
        return this.wordArr;
    }
}
```

RandomWordController.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomWordController{
    public static String getRandomWord(RandomWordModel x){
        Random rand = new Random();
        String wordArr[] = x.getWordArr();
        return wordArr[rand.nextInt(wordArr.length)]; 
    }
}
```

As the functionality requirement you provided is rather simple there is really no need for an MVC framework as you can see. The model for your question is simply a String array and the controller only requires a single function of random word which is why my initial recommendation for going simple. Hope this helps you see how it can be converted to MVC nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you so much but it is for a class and we are supposed to create an MCV model for it. Otherwise, I'd know how to do it but I'm having a hard time with the MVC model and how to get user input from it and display it back.

Comment: @juliamelo See my modified answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forget to initialize the arraylist. Try to initialize ArrayList as :

```
List<String> randomWords= new ArrayList<String>();
```

The working snippet is :

```
private ArrayList<String> randomWords = new ArrayList<String>();;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    rep1 obj = new rep1();
    obj.putWord("user1");
    obj.putWord("user2");
    obj.putWord("user3");
    System.out.println(obj.randomWords);
    Object[] object = obj.getWord();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(object));
}

public void RandomWordModel() {

}

public String putWord(String userWords) {
    randomWords.add(userWords);
    return userWords;
}

public Object[] getWord() {
    Collections.shuffle(randomWords);

    return randomWords.toArray();
}
```